# Descending order list of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Anyone may help me to find the problem in this javaScript code , actually i want to take input from user and the taken should be sorted in Descending order .

Code is -

```
<html>

<body>
    <h2><u>Sorting the array in Descending order</u></h2>
    <script>  
         var number=document.getElementById("D").value;  
         document.write(number);
         function Sort_Number(x, y) 
        {
            return y - x;
        }
       documentgetElementbyId(number.sort(Sort_Number)) = Af;
       </script>  
       <form>
       <label for="fname">Enter the values - </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="nm"  id="D" ><br><br>
       <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="Sort_Number()"><br><br>
       <label for="fname">Descending values are - </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="nm" id="Af"><br><br>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: should be document.getElementById no `documentgetElementbyId ` you are missing "."

Comment: i have put . now  but still not working

Comment: @prabhaslal Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). Try using your browser’s [debug capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a). See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](/q/25385173/4642212). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: [JS docs](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) and [JS tutorials](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) are all available. Why do you pass an array into `getElementById`? Why do you expect `onclick="Sort_Number()"` to do anything? Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: Why do two of your text inputs have the same `name`? Why do your labels have `for="fname"` but no element with the ID `fname` exists? `= Af` makes no sense because you can’t assign to a function call; you could assign something to a _property_, but not `Af`, because assigning an element doesn’t make sense in this context. And relying on the global property `Af` to exist is [bad practice](/q/3434278/4642212). [`sort`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is an array method. Where are you creating an array? Go over JS and HTML basics again.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is executed immediately, so the only thing called by the button is `Sort_Number()`, and that function requires the paramters `x` and `y` which you don't provide in `onclick="Sort_Number()"`. You want to use `Sort_Number(x, y)` as the compare function when you call `number.sort`, and you will need to call another function on the button press to actually carry it out; it won't just execute the contents of the `<script>` tag again. Your script tag here should only be functions.
So for my solution I'm making another function `Sort()` that turns `document.getElementById("D").value` into an array of integers, sorts it in descending order, and outputs it to `Af`:

```
function Sort() {
  var number = document.getElementById("D").value.split(" "); //splits string into array
  for(let i = -1; ++i < number.length; number[i] = parseInt(number[i])); //turns strings into integers
  number = number.sort(Sort_Number); //sorts the array
  document.getElementById("Af").value = number.toString().replace(/,/gi, " "); //outputs array with spaces instead of commas
  return;
}
```

Then in your button you'd use `onclick="Sort()"`.

So the whole thing would look like this:

```html
<html>

<body>
    <h2><u>Sorting the array in Descending order</u></h2>
    <script>
         function Sort_Number(x, y) 
        {
            return y - x;
        }
         function Sort() {
            var number = document.getElementById("D").value.split(" ");
            for(let i = -1; ++i < number.length; number[i] = parseInt(number[i]));
            number = number.sort(Sort_Number);
            document.getElementById("Af").value = number.toString().replace(/,/gi, " ");
            return;
        }
       </script>  
       <form>
       <label for="fname">Enter the values - </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="nm"  id="D" ><br><br>
       <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="Sort()"><br><br>
       <label for="fname">Descending values are - </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="nm" id="Af"><br><br>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the user must separate each number with one space, if you want a different separator you can change the parameter used in `split(" ")`

Comment: It is a pleasure sir thanks for help .

Answer (score 0):

If you are not submitting the form, I don't know if it's necessary to wrap in form tag.

considering that you have only 1 text field for input numbers, You need to consider to add some char to use split method in javascript, in this case, I will consider a simple '-'.

First, let's start to separate your elements to be more clearly

```
   <h2><u>Sorting the array in Descending order</u></h2>

   <div>
       <label for="numbers">Enter the values - </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="numbers"  id="numbers" ><br><br>
       <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="handleSortNumber()"><br><br>
   </div>

   <div>
      <label for="result">Descending values are - </label><br>
      <input type="text" name="result" id="result"><br><br>
   </div>
```

Second, you can keep the inputs elements in a variable

```
<script>
...
  const inputValues = document.getElementById("numbers");
  const output = document.getElementById("result");
...
</script>
```

Now, you can create a handleSortNumber but don't forget that you have a string with values separated with '-' in your input, and now you need to split them, in javascript you can use the method 'split'

```
function handleSortNumber() {

   const splitedValues = inputValues.value.toString().split('-');
   ...
}
```

Now, splitedValues will have a array of String and we can to convert each one to a number, and we can use a map to pass for each element.

```
function handleSortNumber() {
    ...

    const numbers = splitedValues.map(value => Number(value));
    ...
}
```

Finally, you can sort a number and insert the result into a output

```
function handleSortNumber() {
...

    const sortedNumbers = numbers.sort(function compare(a, b) {
          return b - a;
        })
        output.value = sortedNumbers.join('-')
    }
}
```

Full code:

```html
<html>

<body>
    <h2><u>Sorting the array in Descending order</u></h2>

   <div>
       <label for="numbers">Enter the values - </label><br>
       <input type="text" name="numbers"  id="numbers" ><br><br>
       <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="handleSortNumber()"><br><br>
   </div>

    <div>
      <label for="result">Descending values are - </label><br>
      <input type="text" name="response" id="result"><br><br>
    </div>
   
    <script>
      const inputValues = document.getElementById("numbers");
      const output = document.getElementById("result");
      

      
      function handleSortNumber() {
        const splitedValues = inputValues.value.toString().split('-');
        const numbers = splitedValues.map(value => Number(value));

        const sortedNumbers = numbers.sort(function compare(a, b) {
          return b - a;
        })
        output.value = sortedNumbers.join('-')
      }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```